# dispatch queue for NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I'm using `NSRunLoop` to perform some side tasks (in big legacy code).
Now I'm using SocketRocket which is using dispatch queues to define where notification should be received. I need to make SocketRocket to post this notification to my `NSRunLoop`.

With current implementation Socket rocket posts notification to main thread and than notification is passed back to proper tread using run loop. I don't like this extra step.

Can I get/create dispatch queue assisted with specific `NSRunLoop` (which is not associated with main thread)?

`dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated and this would be a perfect solution for me.

I don't want to modify SocketRocket but so far I don't see better solution.